# How do i create a function that adds already drawn blocks to a list?

Tags: kotlin

currently i have an uni project which involves on building a simpler version of the game arkanoid (ball that reflects on racket destroying blocks) on canvas using kotlin. We use intelij. Im trying to create a function that based on a mutable list of bricks, builds a brick on canvas and adds it to the list, and when the ball hits it , it disapears and gets removed from that list.

So far i have this

```kotlin
enum class TypeOfBrick(val color: Int, val points: Int){
    Sb(SILVER,0),
    Wb(WHITE,1),
    Ob(ORANGE,2),
    Cb(CYAN,3),
    Gb(GREEN,4),
    Rb(RED,6),
    Bb(BLUE,7),
    Mb(MAGENTA,8),
    Yb(YELLOW,9),
}

data class Brick(val x: Int, val y: Int, val height: Int = Brick_Height, val width: Int = Brick_Width, val typeOfBrick: TypeOfBrick)

val brickList = mutableListOf<TypeOfBrick>()

fun createBrick(x: Int = Random.nextInt(32, Width-Brick_Width), y: Int = Random.nextInt(3*Brick_Height, 9*Brick_Height), typeOfBrick: TypeOfBrick): Brick{
    return Brick(x, y, Brick_Height, Brick_Width, typeOfBrick)
}

fun Canvas.drawBrick(brick: Brick){
    this.drawRect(brick.x, brick.y, Brick_Width, Brick_Height, brick.typeOfBrick.color)
}

fun addBricksToList(canvas: Canvas, brick: Brick) {
    /*
     * HERE: I know inside here i can use the for loop,
     * but i just cant seem to do it.
     */
}
```

Comment: Is there a given pattern of bricks to place? You can do a nested for loop, looping through the number of rows and columns and creating blocks based on row and column. Your question says "already drawn" but surely you haven't drawn them before they are part of the list, right?

Comment: yes i haven't drawn them yet, my bad. There is a pattern of bricks, it has 3 blocks that are divided into 3 colums and 8 lines of bricks. One line of bricks = 3 same color bricks. How do i do the nested loop to create the bricks?